# Creating and using Library Projects in Nsight Tegra

Tags: android, android-ndk, nsight, tegra

I'm trying to use the newest Nsight Tegra 3.0 to create my APK. My project has a few components...one of them is a native dynamic library (SO) and the other pieces are several library projects from google for their Google-Play-Services and their LicenseService. Those are library projects in Eclipse but I can't seem to find a way to include them in VS2013 with NSight Tegra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need link to your native code,
you can set .so at Project properies>Configuration Properties>Linker>General>Additional Library Directories and Project properies>Configuration Properties>Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies,

if just link to java code,  you can set at Project properies>Configuration Properties>Ant Buid>Additional Dependencies.